# Can we execute callback to JavaScript's forEach asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

a.forEach(item => {
  ...
});
console.log('all done');
```

Is it ever possible in browser or node environment that it console 'all done' before the forEach completes its execution? If yes then when?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your code is synchronous so it can never happen unless you explicitly execute the `.forEach` function in an async block.

Comment: how can I do that. Could you please give an example for me.

Comment: Yes, https://jsfiddle.net/4udkgLqd/

Answer (score 0):

No. `forEach` is a synchronous function.

It is possible to call asynchronous functions from within it, and they might not have completed, but the loop itself will have done.